# JSONObject Azure Function

Tags: android, json, azure-functions

I am having trouble getting my Azure Function to accept a Json object from a Android Device. I believe it must be formatted wrong as it accepts Json from c# (NewtonSoft). I am recieving

```
Http status code 400.
```

The azure function

```
[FunctionName("TestFunc")]
public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)]HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
```

The code that is causing the problem

```
commsMsg = await req.Content.ReadAsAsync<CommsMsg>();
```

commsMsg is null when receiving from the android client. This is CommsMsg:

```
public class CommsMsg:ICommsMsg
{
    public int commandCode { get; set; }
    public List<Extra> extras { get; set; }
}
```

And Extra:

```
public class Extra
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
    public Extra() { }
    public Extra(String name, string value)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

Extra just name value strings. I think the array of extras is causing the problem.
I can not debug locally as if I run the function on localhost in Visual Studio 2017 the Android Emulator will not connect to localhost on

```
"http://10.0.2.2:7071/api/TestFunc
```

Or

```
http://102.168.1.10:7071/api/TestFunc
```

So I can not examime what the emulator is sending. In Android Studio I have:

```
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 obj.put("commandCode",100);
 JSONObject extras = new JSONObject();
 extras.put("val1",101);
 extras.put("val2",102);
 obj.put("Extras",extras);
 JsonObjectRequest req = new JsonObjectRequest
            (Request.Method.GET, url,obj, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    //not getting here
                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //bad request 400 here

                }
            });
```

The errorListener is saying Http status code is 400. It would easier to solve if I could debug locally but I won't work. Have I formatted the Json incorrectly?

Comment: you can try NGROK to proxy external address (I assume your emulator would be able to connect to) to your localhost

Comment: I got NGROK working and it'd very useful - anybody reading this don't forget to use ngrok http 7071 --host-header localhost otherwise it wont work which is from an excellent blog https://hackernoon.com/using-ngrok-with-azure-functions-7e209e96538c  ..... however the Android client is still not posting anything to the service but at least the service is being hit now thanks to ngrok :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't get the JSONobject to work so in the end I used GSON eg:

```
String json = gson.toJson(commsMsg);
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

I used the very usefull GNROK to connect to localhost which worked very well. I followed this tutoroial which worked very well.

```
 https://hackernoon.com/using-ngrok-with-azure-functions-7e209e96538c
```